# How Do I Order ID In a Certain Way?

Tags: php

I'm trying to order a certain ID from highest to lowest.

Say, I have 5 id's.

1
2
3
4
5

I'm trying to have it order my most recent/highest ID.

Like,

5
4
3
2
1

Here is the code that "posts" it (it's for a blog, btw)

```
$post = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM blog ORDER BY id") or die(mysql_error());
```

I'm sure there is a way, but can't understand how to very well.

Comment: Where are those ids? In a database table? In an array?

Comment: Well your question sounds like a riddle. I would say it would be most easy if your system has only one ID. Then you would do nothing at all, whatever it is what you're doing (hint: you have missed to show your code, there are a thousand ways how these five IDs could be represented in code)

Comment: Why the downvote? This is a legitimate question, and the answer does not care about the input type. Specifically, it will pay attention to type AND maintain the index.

Comment: @L0j1k: If you move your mouse-pointer over the downvote button, you will see a discription for what down-votes are given.

Comment: Interesting. Thanks, I didn't know about that before. Why do some downvotes NOT have any information? +1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have a look at `arsort()` and related functions from the PHP Manual: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.arsort.php

This answer is assuming that you have put your values into an array: `$foo[] = { 1, 3, 4, 2, 5 };` However, it is the general sentiment of the people watching this that you have not given enough information about your situation to properly answer the question. I can understand that viewpoint. Generally, you should include a slice of source code that concerns your specific question. Without that, you will probably be downvoted instead of given a proper answer. This is also a good way to show us that you are not simply having StackOverflow do your homework for you. :)

In MySQL, your statement should include the `DESC` keyword for "descending":

```
$post = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM blog ORDER BY id DESC") or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: more a comment than an answer. you also make the assumption this is about arrays. I can not see any array in the question (sure it would be useful to use arrays, but you never know); better teach the OP how to write questions that are more precise.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably easiest to do this in your MySQL statement, so you'd add the keyword `DESC` to the end of your query, changing it to

```
SELECT * FROM blog ORDER BY id DESC
```

Adding the `DESC` (for "descending") keyword to the `ORDER BY` clause will mean that SQL will order them with the highest value first and the lowest value last, in contrast to the default behavior (which can be specified with the `ASC` keyword).